# DataGridView row's background color is not changing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to change the background color of the DGV's row based on particular condition at load even in Windows Form. But I can't see any change of color to any DGV's row. Could anyone tell me how can I solve this problem?

```
private void frmSecondaryPumps_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = DeviceData.BindData("SECONDARY_PUMPS".ToUpper());
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[column.Name] != null)
                        {
                            if (row.Cells[column.Name].Value.ToString() == "ON")
                                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                            if (row.Cells[column.Name].Value.ToString() == "OFF")
                                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        }
                    }
                }

                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: why not set `BackColor` instead of `ForeColor`

Comment: I've tried this as well, but I can't see any change in row color in any row of DGV

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the best place would be to set the BackColor in the `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView`, something on these lines.

```
private void grid1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = grid1.Rows[e.RowIndex];// get you required index
    // check the cell value under your specific column and then you can toggle your colors
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Comment: As said below by King_Rob, Cellformatting will continously fire the event even when scrolling. Use it with caution.

Comment: That event multiple fired.

Answer (score 21):

One of the problems with using either the `cellformatting`, `databindingcomplete` or even `paint` events is that they get fired multiple times.  From what I've gathered, there is an issue with the `datagridview` control in that you cannot change the color of any of the cells until AFTER the form has been shown.  Thus methods that run, or events that fire before `Shown()` is called will not change the color.  The events that are sited as the solution to the problem usually work, but since they're called many times, may not be the most efficient answer.

Probably the simplest solution to the issue is to put your code to fill/color your grids in the `Shown()` method of your form instead of the constructor.  Below is a link to a post in the msdn forums that tipped me off to the solution, it's marked as the answer about 3/4 of the way down the page.

[MSDN forums post with the Solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/31ef832b-2fe2-4554-bf0c-8495f9e85ede/)

Comment: This should be the right answer. And just to add implementation details: Use the Load event to set a flag and then the Visible event to set the backcolor.

Comment: This is the right ANSWER. Improves the performance as it doesn't fire multiple times like it does while using cellformatting & other handlers

Answer (score 8):

King_Rob is correct. I had the same issue so I will just post my implementation since the other suggestions here are far from optimal.

Add the events handlers (in designer or constructor):

```
this.Load += UserControl_Load; // or form or any control that is parent of the datagridview
dataGridView1.VisibleChanged += DataGridView1_VisibleChanged;
```

In the load event hander method add a flag

```
private bool _firstLoaded;
private void UserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _firstLoaded = true;
}
```

And finally in the visible event handler method:

```
private void DataGridView1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_firstLoaded && dataGridView1.Visible)
    {
        _firstLoaded = false;
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Least hacky answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer but I'm just facing exactly the same problem now.

I have some general solution for things that don't work properly in the constructor - use a timer

Set it for some short time like 100 ms. Then in constructor you will have

```
timer1.Enabled=true
```

and in timer_Tick event:

```
timer1.Enabled=false

and all the code that doesn't work in constructor goes here...
```

It worked for me every time.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is when you run this code. You run it with the trigger `_Load`, that is why it is not coloring, when you run the same code with the trigger `_Shown` on the form, the coloring will work. Load is triggered when the form is loading, so there can still be some behind-the-scenes code running after your code. Shown trigger runs after everything is done and the form is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

put it on the load page event

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dGrid1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[12].Style.BackColor = Color.SeaShell;

        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to change the Datagrid item color

```
Datagrid1.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
Datagrid1.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

Answer (score -2):

This code is fast, easy and does not consume memory!

Use this code, for example, inside the CellEndEdit event

```
 `try{
 //your code
 }
 catch(Exception){
 //your exception
 }
finally{
yourDataGridView.Visible = false;
 yourDataGridView.Visible = true;
}
```

`

Comment: how that even helps the user?

Comment: Maybe it is the same as with other Microsoft Products and a shutdown and restart (`Visible = false; Visible = true`) helps indeed?

Comment: If it works (and it works for me) it means it helps. do you agree with me?