# Changing the row background color of DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have searched a lot and found some methods to change a rows background color in datagrid view but it does not work at all,Can you help me find my mistake?

```
dataGridViewResult.DataSource = morgan.GetResult().Tables[5];
        dataGridViewResult.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Beige;
        dataGridViewResult.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dataGridViewResult.Rows[7].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dataGridViewResult.Rows[40].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dataGridViewResult.Rows[11].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dataGridViewResult.Rows[19].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dataGridViewResult.Rows[28].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dataGridViewResult.Rows[35].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;

        dataGridViewResult.Rows[35].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: The code you've posted is changing the `ForeColor`, not the `BackColor`.  Is this what you intended?  Paste error?  Side note: you change row 35 twice, making the first change overwridden.

Comment: @OhBeWise In fact I have tested most of cellstyles and they don't work at all.It does not show any errors It just doesn't change the color.About row 35 yes it is my mistake but it does not change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code might work:

```
private void grid1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = grid1.Rows[e.RowIndex];// get you required index
    // check the cell value under your specific column and then you can toggle your colors
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

More info: [DataGridView row's background color is not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527963/datagridview-rows-background-color-is-not-changing)

Comment: @MajidHojati I checked it, its working. What is the Error or what wrong

Comment: Does this not set the row's color for each cell that is found in the row? That means you're repetitively setting the same value.

Answer (score 1):

m.lansers answer is correct. Have you bound the method he used to the DataGridViews CellFormatting event? as in:

```
dataGridView.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(grid1_CellFormatting);
```

Additionally an alternative shorter bit of code would be to just use:

```
e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```